# Queue calls to asynchronous method BeginSend of a socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I need to queue *BeginSend* calls to a socket and I need them to be executed chronologically. To do this I used a semaphore to signal when the callback function is clear to go.
Most of the time it works because each asynchronous callback is executed on a separated thread, but occasionally the same thread used in current callback is used in the newly asynchronous call. When this happens, that thread is locked waiting for the semaphore to be released, but because the same thread that was supposed to clear the semaphore, is waiting for it to be cleared, the thread is locked forever.

To illustrate the problem here is a test code:

```
static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);
static IList<byte[]> buffer = new List<byte[]>();
static void Main()
{
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 8 }), 123));
    while (true) // data feed
    {
        lock (buffer)
        {
            buffer.Add(new byte[1460]);
            if (buffer.Count == 1)
                socket.BeginSend(buffer[0], 0, 1460, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket); // calls BeginSend if the buffer was empty before 
        }
    }
}

static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("in " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    semaphore.WaitOne();
    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    lock(buffer)
    {
        buffer.RemoveAt(0); // removes data that was sent
        if (buffer.Count > 0) // if there is more data to send calls BeginSend again
            socket.BeginSend(buffer[0], 0, 1460, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
    }
    semaphore.Release();
    Console.WriteLine("out " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

and here is the output:
[image]
Because thread 10 was transferred to a new callback, without giving a chance for the previous callback to exit and clear the semaphore, the thread is locked forever.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: I did not know that Socket.BeginRead can invoke the callback synchronously. This creates hideous reentrancy problems. Are you sure? Can you post a screenshot of the callstack to prove it? It should have two stack frames in SendCallback.

Comment: Use a BlockingCollection to keep track of the data to send. Solves 2 issues: maintain order and removes the deadlock

Comment: @usr http://imgur.com/EZFdXJX

Comment: Indeed. That's a hideous trap. Probably added in the name of efficiency. This also makes BeginSend not non-blocking because arbitrary code can run as part of the call.

Comment: You've got a race condition now because you are accessing buffer outside of the lock.

Comment: @usr yes, but it's not modified outside the lock

Comment: You're not allowed to read and write to it concurrently. You're doing that, though. Reading is not safe in the presence of writers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

switch to tasks:

Nice msdn article [Tasks and the APM Pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx)

```
public Task<int> SendAsync(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags flags)
{
   var result = socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, flags, _ => { }, socket);
   return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result,(r) => socket.EndSend(r));
}
```

things get a little easier now:

Using a default [BlockingCollection<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a concurrent queue. It's thread save and removes the explicit lock on the list

```
static BlockingCollection<byte[]> buffer = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

public async void Main()
{
   Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
   socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 8 }), 123));
   while (!buffer.IsCompleted)
   {
      var data = buffer.Take();
      await SendAsync(socket, data, 0, data.Length, 0);
   }
   Console.ReadLine();            
}
```

Non blocking send and order is maintained while not needing the semaphore.

Comment: I don't what Tasks would change. Task completion can still be synchronous and cause reentrancy problems. You have changed the problem structure to a while loop which avoid the problems but there probably was a reason the OP needed the lock and be safe against concurrent writes.

Comment: @usr Up to the OP to update the question and explain about the reasoning, perhaps we can adjust the answer to fit his needs better.

Comment: In my real problem, a thread adds packet by packet as they arrive to a buffer list and calls BeginSend if there was no packet in buffer before. Then BeginSend callback function calls BeginSend again if there are more packets to send. Not sure how Tasks would help. It would basically transform BeginSend in a synchronous method.

Comment: @Chris, it just looks like a sync method but in reality it is not.